# How to pass value into textbox from Page to main form in WPF?

Tags: wpf

Can't set value to textbox from Page to form

I have a main form with frame where I load page
Frame1.NavigationService.Navigate(New PieDonut2DChart.pagOpenTicketsByMember()) and textbox txtFrame1.
Now I want from page set value:
Dim mainForm as frmMain1 = New frmMain1()
mainform.txtFrame1.Text = "Test"
But code not working.

Comment: When I see code with `frmMain` that sounds like you are using WinForms.  Are you using `.xaml` files to design your form?

Comment: Yes, I use XAML file. I just gave name for Window frmMain1. This is just name.